# Chi-square Test with High Sample Size and Unbalanced Data

Tags: chi-squared-test, p-value, normalization, unbalanced-classes

I have a data set which has high values. I want to make a chi-square test on this set.

```
         +--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+     +----------+
         | 15-19  | 20-24   | 25-29   | 30-34   | 35-39   |     ||  SUM    |
+--------+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-----+----------+
| Male   | 9639   | 281060  | 1355555 | 2257670 | 2686581 |     || 6590505 |
+--------+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-----+----------+
| Female | 127728 | 993121  | 2057165 | 2536860 | 2710454 |     || 8425328 |
+--------+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-----+----------+
         |        |         |         |         |         |     ||         |
+========+========+=========+=========+=========+=========+=====+==========+
| SUM    | 137367 | 1274181 | 3412720 | 4794530 | 5397035 |     || 15015833|
+--------+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-----+----------+
```

When I calculate the **expected value** with the formula, I got the following table:

*(For the first column and first row: 6590505 * 137367 / 15015833 = 60290,9)*

```
EXPECTED VALUE TABLE
         +---------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
         | 15-19   | 20-24  | 25-29   | 30-34   | 35-39   |
+--------+---------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
| Male   | 60290,9 | 559243 | 1497856 | 2104337 | 2368779 |
+--------+---------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
| Female | 77076,1 | 714938 | 1914864 | 2690193 | 3028256 |
+--------+---------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
```

**Then, subtract expected from actual, square it, then divide by expected:**

*(For the first column and first row: 
(9639 - 60290,9)*(9639 - 60290,9) / (60290,9) = 42553,9)*

```
         +---------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
         | 15-19   | 20-24  | 25-29   | 30-34   | 35-39   |
+--------+---------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
| Male   | 42553,9 | 138376 | 13519   | 11172,6 | 42637,3 |
+--------+---------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
| Female | 33286,8 | 108241 | 10574,9 | 8739,52 | 33352   |
+--------+---------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
```

So, **Chi-square** is the sum of all cells which is: 42553,9 + 138376 + ... + 8739,52 + 33352 = 442453

**Chi-square = 442453**

Degrees of Freedom:
Multiply (rows − 1) by (columns − 1), which is
(2 - 1) * (5 - 1) = 4

**Degrees of Freedom(DF) = 4**
I choose **Confidence Level = 0.05**

So, when I look it up to **Chi-square Distribution Table**, the number is **9.49**.
[image: Chi-square Distribution Table]
Obviously it's not proper to compare with **9.49** and **442453**. What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Everything you did was correct. `R` provides the same answer:

```r
    male <- c(9639, 281060, 1355555, 2257670, 2686581)
    female <- c(127728, 993121, 2057165, 2536860, 2710454)
    data <- matrix(c(male, female), nrow=2, byrow=TRUE)    
    chisq.test(x = data)
```

The output being:

```r
    Pearson's Chi-squared test
    data:  data
    X-squared = 442453, df = 4, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

What you might have missed, is that sample size can actually be too large to make meaningful use of p-values. See for a discussion of this [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/262b/854628d8e2b073816935d82b5095e1703977.pdf/) (Lin, M., Lucas Jr, H. C., & Shmueli, G. (2013). Research commentary - too big to fail: large samples and the p-value problem. Information Systems Research, 24(4), 906-917.).

Don't rely for your interpretation on p-values when your samples are very large. The p-value is just the probability of getting this or more extreme data if the null hypothesis is true, with huge data this probability can get arbitrarily small.

Edit: I assumed that in your table in each cell there is the number of persons of a certain age and sex, and thus your sample size is huge. If this is not the case, Chi-Squared test may not be correct test.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. I tried to normalize the data (with dividing all cells with a fixed number like _10000_ or _50000_) and I found that when total sample size go down to **300**, the case is looking **independent**. But as soon as I divide the cells with smaller fixed number to get higher sample size, it's looking **dependent**. I really confused about what should I do with this large data. I didn't find anything about **maximum sample size** for _chi-square test_; only thing I found that **minimum sample size** for _chi-square test_ which is **50** as a recommendation.

Answer (score 6):

As a companion to the answer by @LuckyPal , you might want to look at ways to examine the effect size, and also determine if the differences you observe are practically important.

One simple way is to look at the proportions for each column of males and females. Code in R follows.  Note that each row sums to 1.  Note that the proportions for columns 4 and 5 are higher for males, and proportions for columns 1, 2, and 3 are higher for females.

```r
    male <- c(9639, 281060, 1355555, 2257670, 2686581)
    female <- c(127728, 993121, 2057165, 2536860, 2710454)
    data <- matrix(c(male, female), nrow=2, byrow=TRUE)

    PT = prop.table(data, margin=1)

    round(PT, 3)  

       ###       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
       ### [1,] 0.001 0.043 0.206 0.343 0.408
       ### [2,] 0.015 0.118 0.244 0.301 0.322
```

Another approach is to use Cramer's *V*, which is an effect size statisitc that ranges from 0 to 1.  Note that a Cramer's *V* of 0.17 is relatively small.

```r
    if(!require(vcd)){install.packages("vcd")}

    library(vcd)
    
    assocstats(data)
    
        ### Cramer's V        : 0.172
```

Answer (score 0):

The key point here is that the $\chi^2$ test is *homogeneous*. Ok, the p-value is overemphasized in research, but here the core idea of the test is "wrong".
Multiplying your table by $\lambda$ (ideally, taking $\lambda$ identical samples) you'll see your statistic grow by a $\lambda$ factor.
Try to conduct a $\chi^2$ on a (pseudo)random matrix with "large" numbers (it sufficed to me to use a $4\times 4$ matrix with numbers randomly sampled from $[100,300]$ to obtain really low p-values).

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to determine if the distribution of age bins differs by sex? You could code your age groups as an ordinal variable. Then you could run an ordinal logistic regression of `polr(Age_bin ~ Sex)`.

The polr function is in the nnet package.

Comment: You should add from what R package is `polr`, as it is not in base!